# How can I write a regex to exclude both alphanumeric characters and spaces?

Tags: regex

I have the following regex pattern, which strips out non, alpha-numerics.

> **[^0-9A-Za-z]**

Works pretty good.

I was hoping to mod this regex so it looks for alphanumerics AND spaces. How can I tweak it so it also accepts spaces?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put a space into the brackets

```
[^0-9A-Za-z ]
```

You're question is also slightly ambiguous.  I'm assuming you're looking to **exclude** both alphanumerics and spaces.

Comment: thanks mate. I've got some sql udf that returns a string, with all non-alphanumerics stripped out. I wanted to make it strip out everthing BUT alpha/numberic/spaces. (and i replace all spaces with a '-' character). works great. thanks. (DB is sql2008, btw).